# Set Angularjs constants at project startup from $http.GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my application I have an orchestration service that gets the uris from different services that register with it. `service_1` and `service_2` could be on different machines but one registered, the uris of their machines will be stored.

In my other application which makes use of that orchestration service, I want to call to the orchestration service to get the uris to use, but then I want to set them as Angular constants, or at least be able to use the uri's values.

So this is the service that's going to be using the 'constant' which is the uri pulled from orchestration service:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('data.model-view', ['restapi'])
        .factory('MVService', MVService);

    MVService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'exception', 'logger', 'restapi'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function MVService($http, $q, exception, logger, restapi) {

        var HOST = restapi.mvservice.HOST;
        var MODULE = restapi.mvservice.MODULE;
    ...
    //below is an example of what will use the above host/module in order to 
    //get the data needed for this application

    function getModels() {
        return $http.get(HOST + MODULE + '/model/retrieveAll')
            .then(success)
            .catch(fail);

        function success(response) {
            return response.data;
        }
        function fail(e) {
            return exception.catcher('XHR Failed for retrieveAll')(e);
        }
    }
```

So then this is `restapi` module where I'd like the constants to be set, so I can have access to them throughout the application, but I need to get them from the orchestration service first.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var data = '';
    angular
        .module('restapi', [])
        .factory('restapi', function($http, exception) {
            var HOST = %%ORCSERVICE%%;
            var MODULE = '/orchestration/service/rest/data';

            return $http.get(HOST + MODULE)
            .then(success)
            .catch(fail);

            function success(response) {
                //so at this point I can actually access the data I need
                //with a console.debug(response.data);
                return response.data;
            }

            function fail(e) {
                return exception.catcher('XHR Failed to reach orc')(e);
            }
        }).constant('restapi', constant());

    function constant() {
        //set constants here based on the data pulled from above

       //ideally I want the result of this to be like
       //{
       //    mvservice: {
       //        'HOST': 'http://xxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com'
       //        'MODULE': '/rest/service/whatever'
       //    },
       //    ... //other service here
       //}
    }

})();
```

Like I say in the comment above, I can actually get the data I need (the uris) from the `$http.get` immediately above. I'd just like then to be able to get the data set as a constant, or at least in a form that I can access it. Because when `MVService` spins up, it needs the its own uir from the orchestration service in order to be able to make its rest calls. Sorry might be a little confusing, let me know if there is a need for clarification.

Answer (score 5):

Try bootstrapping app after getting necessary data:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng']),
    http = injector.get('$http');

http.get(HOST + MODULE).then(function (result) {
    app.value('restapi', result.data);
    angular.bootstrap(document, [app.name]);
});
```

Comment: That was awesome. I never knew about stuff like that.

Comment: Where would something like this go? Inside `success` where I have access to the data? I'm newer to Angular so sorry if obvious. Just wondering how this applies to me. Or are there any articles you'd recommend about this topic? I'd assume as well I'd ditch the whole `constant` stuff.

Comment: Also, how would I access the data say from the `MVService` function? The same way I currently am?

Comment: @erp just inject `restapi` wherever you want

Comment: Okay cool, but where would I put the above code, inside the success function? Just having a tough time figuring out how your code directly applies to mine (sorry)

Comment: @erp  you place this code outside everything. It replaces your second code sample

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way :

If you want to use angular.constant you can do it by getting the url by delaying bootstrap of angular until you get your values. Because you can't set constant once the ng-app has loaded. To do this see karaxuna's answer.

Another way is to perform your angular queries in the constructor of your service. Because the routing and call of controllers won't happen until all promise of the service's instantiation phase will be resolved. So you can store the result of your request as fields of your service and then access it without any racing problems on the controllers/directives/angular.run parts of your application.